# Mongodb will not start. libboost_filesystem.so.1.78.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, archlinux, systemctl

Something must be broken, or maybe there is something I am not seeing.
I do:
sudo systemctl status mongodb.service

But I get this error:

```
Jan 26 10:47:49 MacBookPro systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Jan 26 10:47:49 MacBookPro mongod[12272]: /usr/bin/mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.78.0: cannot>
Jan 26 10:47:49 MacBookPro systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Jan 26 10:47:49 MacBookPro systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 26 10:47:49 MacBookPro systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
```

I have been reading: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MongoDB
And because there is no mongod.lock file I do:

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --repair
```

But the error persists:

```
mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.78.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What do you  guys think is happening? Thanks in advance. Btw I am using BlackArch.

I have tried a full update and upgrade. My system says it is fully updated, but maybe it is not?

Comment: How did you install `mongod`?

Comment: I am using the one that came installed with BlackArch Linux

Comment: What is ```pacman -Qo `which mongod` ```?

Comment: I get error: No package owns which mongod

Comment: Maybe you use a different shell than me. `\`which mongod\`` is just to get the full path to the executable.  Presumably you know, or can find, where `mongod` is installed. `pacman -Qo full_path_to_the_file_you_are_interested_in` should report which package the file belongs to.  Package managers typical install, if necessary, any dependencies required for the packages.  For some reason, your system is having trouble finding `libboost_filesystem.so.1.78.0`.  Either it's installed and can't be found, or it's not installed.  There are remedies for each.

Comment: Interestingly, my `mongod` has no `libboost` dependency.

Comment: Mine is located at /usr/bin/mongod and it is owned by mongodb 5.0.7-1

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected `mongodb-bin` instead.  Curious that package `mongodb` has that low of a version number.  I thought Arch, and therefore BlackArch would have more recent versions.  What does `pacman -Qi mongodb` say?  Which repo did it come from?  I also wonder what `pacman -Qkk mongodb` might reveal.  I don't run Arch/BlackArch, so you'll need to interpret the output.  Other `pacman` and/or `pactree` queries might be interesting too.

Comment: Depends On      : curl  libstemmer  snappy  gperftools  boost-libs  pcre  yaml-cpp

Comment: URL             : https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community

Comment: pacman -Qkk mongodb
                                                   mongodb: 27 total files, 0 altered files

Comment: Was installed as a dependency for another package.

Comment: It comes from the blackarch repo

Comment: Any problems shown with the output of `pacman -Dk`?

Comment: Yes lots of errors. Hundreds of messages that say: "error: file owned by 'mypy' and 'python-mypy'"                                                 and also it says "no database errors have been found"

Comment: https://blackarch.org/tools.html doesn't show `mongodb`.  I don't think I understand BlackArch's package management.  Perhaps it could be figured out with a live system using `pacman` and friends.  Have you tried just re-installing `mongodb` or `mongodb-bin` - both of those are in Arch's user repos.